# How to have log4j create a file with pattern like unsent_20190904015350_001.csv

Tags: java, log4j2

I need to log some data into a csv file.
I am using `log4j2` and have configured the log properties using java code.
I am using the pattern `unsent_%d{yyyyMMddhhmmss}_%i.csv` which is creating the file naming format as `unsent_20190904015350_1.csv`.

But I want the file naming format as `unsent_20190904015350_001.csv`.

Is there a way to achieve it in `log4j2`

Comment: what is the 00 for?

Comment: I need a 3 digit naming convention, like 001, 002 and so on.